# align string to a pattern in perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have chunks of strings within square brackets, like this:

```
[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] [p3 text3/label3] [...
```

and so on.

What's inside each chunk isn't important. But sometimes there are stray chunks of text that are NOT surrounded by square brackets. For example:

```
[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] textX/labelX  [p3 text3/label3] [...] textY/labelY textZ/labelZ [...]
```

I thought I had this solved fine with regex in perl until I realized that I have only catered to the cases where there is a single stray text at the beginning, the middle, or the end of the text, but not where we might have two stray cases together. (like the Y and Z chunks above).

So I realized that regular expressions in perl only catch the first matching pattern? How could the above problem be solved then?

### Edit:

The problem is to ensure that all *should be* surrounded by brackets. Square brackets are never recursive. When surrounding a phrase with brackets, the p-value depends on the "label" value. For eg, if a stray unbracketed phrase is

```
li/IN
```

then it should turn  into:

```
[PP li/IN]
```

I guess it is a mix but the only way I can think of solving the bigger problem I'm working on is to turn all of them into bracketed phrases, so the handling is easier. So I've got it working if an unbracketed phrase happens at the beginning, middle and end, but not if two or more happen together.

I basically used a different regex for each position (beginning, middle and end). The one that catches an unbracketed phrase in the middle looks like this:

```
$data =~ s/\] (text)#\/label \[/\] \[selected-p-value $1#\/label\] \[/g;
```

So what I'm doing is just noticing that if a ] comes before and after the text/label pattern, then this one doesn't have brackets. I do something similar for the others too. But I guess this is incredibly un-generic. My regex isn't great!

Comment: I fail to see what the problem is though. Do you want what is inside the [] or outside? Is it possible that [] contains [] ?

Comment: You didn't define a problem: You have text inside square brackets, you have text *outside* brackets. That's a *mix* not a *problem*. Unix shell has a similar "problem" some phrases are commands, some are switches, and some are arguments. And if you want to put the text outside into square brackets, what p-value do you want give it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can solve this using *"only"* regex :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = "[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] textX/labelX  [p3 text3/label3] [...] textY/labelY textZ/labelZ [...]";

s{ ([^\s[]+)|(\[(?:[^[]*)\])     }
 { if( defined $2){ $2 } elsif(defined $1)
    { 
       if($1 =~ m!(.*(?<=/)(.*))!)
       {
         if($2 eq 'labelX')
         {
            "[PP $1]";
         }
         elsif($2 eq 'labelY')
         {
            "[BLA $1]";
         }
         elsif($2 eq 'labelZ')
         {
            "[FOO $1]";
         }
       }
    }
 }xge;

 print;
```

Output :

```
[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] [PP textX/labelX]  [p3 text3/label3] [...] [BLA textY/labelY] [FOO textZ/labelZ] [...]
```

Comment: wow i had no idea regex can do this. a question though (I'm still new at perl) - how can I make this apply to a declared variable? Instead of $_ = ... I just used $string, but then the regex doesn't apply to it.

Comment: @user961627 Just replace $_ with my$string = ... and then apply the replace regex to it like $string =~ s{...

Comment: Do you mind explaining what this means?
([^\s[]+) | (\[(?:[^[]*)\]) 
I've checked regex tutorials but don't quite understand what "?:" being a "passive" or "non-capturing" group means.

Also, could this be extended to pick up not just phrases with or without square brackets, but those that have only a single bracket? eg. [p text/label] p text/label] [p text/label]
So you can see the middle one is missing one of the brackets.

Comment: ok i understand what the first part means: ([^\s[]+)|(\[(?:[^[]*)\])

but i don't understand this: $1 =~ m!(.*(?<=/)(.*))!

Comment: @user961627 That means basically match anything before / and also match anything after it. I could elaborate if you want. Regarding your missing brackets, my solution, and possible any other solution, will not work in that case.

Comment: okay i get that. but why does your solution not work? I'm using Expresso to analyze the expression. I understand that whatever doesn't get defined by ([(?:[^[]*)]), is held in $1, then you go to the conditional with $1 =~ m!(.*(?<=/)(.*))! . Yes please, I would actually like know to know what the m! and ! at the end are doing. But why does this not work? Should not anything that isn't captured in $2 get captured in $1? So wouldn't that include something like **word/label]**  (<- Note this phrase only has a right-side bracket) **Edit** In fact, it _is_ getting captured! (per the regex analyzer)

Comment: Well I told you what the second match does. So why you ask again? :D. The ! and ! are simply delimiter of the regex like / / . The single bracket thing will not work. Because the first regex assumes that there are always two brackets. For arbitrary nesting of brakcets etc. you will need a **WAY** more complex solution.

Comment: @user961627 This is a single case. Try random [] missing and you will see that it will not work.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] textX/labelX  [p3 text3/label3] [...] textY/labelY textZ/labelZ [...]";

# don't split inside the [], i.e. not at blanks that have p\d in front of them
my @items = split(/(?<!p\d)\s+/, $string);
my @new_items;

# modify the items that are not inside []
@new_items = map { ($_ =~ m/\[/) ? $_ :
                    ((split("/",$_))[1] eq ("IN")) ? "[PP $_]" :
                    "[BLA $_]";
                 } @items;

print join(' ', @new_items), "\n";
```

This gives

```
[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] [PP textX/labelX] [p3 text3/label3] [...] [PP textY/labelY] [PP textZ/labelZ] [...]
```

I took it that `PP` was meant as I used it here, otherwise the `map` will have to become a bit more elaborate.

**EDIT**

I have edited the code in response to your comment. If you use

```
"[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] textX/IN  [p3 text3/label3] [...] textY/labelY textZ/labelZ [...]";
```

as a sample string, this is the output:

```
[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] [PP textX/IN] [p3 text3/label3] [...] [BLA textY/labelY] [BLA textZ/labelZ] [...]
```

Just one thing to bear in mind: The regex used with `split` will not work for `pn` with n > 9. If you have such cases, best look for an alternative, because variable length lookbehinds have not been implemented (or at least in my version of Perl (5.10.1) they haven't).

**EDIT 2**

As a reply to your second comment, here's a modified version of the script. You will find that I also added something to the sample string to demonstrate that it now works even if there's no `pn` inside the `[...]`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] textX/IN  [p3 text3/label3] [...] textY/labelY textZ/labelZ [...] xyx/IN [opq rs/abc]";

# we're using a non-greedy match to only capture the contents of one set of [], 
# otherwise we'd simply match everything between the first [ and the last ].
# The parentheses around the match ensure that our delimiter is KEPT.
my @items = split(/(\[.+?\])/, $string);

#print "..$_--\n" for @items;  # uncomment this to see what the split result looks like

# modify the items that are not inside []
my @new_items = map {
                     if (/^\[/) { # items in []
                        $_;
                     }
                     elsif (/(?: \w)|(?:\w )/) { # an arbitrary number of items without []
                       my @new =  map { ($_ =~ m/\[/) ? $_ :
                                        ((split("/",$_))[1] eq ("IN")) ? "[PP $_]" :
                                        "[BLA $_]";
                                      } split;
                     }
                     else { # some items are '', let's just discard those
                     }
                    } @items;

print join(' ', @new_items), "\n";
```

The output is this:

```
[p1 text1/label1] [p2 text2/label2] [PP textX/IN] [p3 text3/label3] [...] [BLA textY/labelY] [BLA textZ/labelZ] [...] [PP xyx/IN] [opq rs/abc]
```

I noticed you already received the help you required, but I thought I could answer your question all the same...

Comment: Thanks! I understand most of your code. This works. However, PP is not the only choice, the choice would depend on the label value. Can I somehow add a conditional or a processing statement after the : in the map block? Something like:
map { ($_ =~ m/\[/) ? $_ : @bits = split("/", $_); if($bits[1] eq "IN"){$_ = "[PP $_]";} else {$_ = "[BLA $_]";} } @items;

Comment: okay - a problem here. I'm trying to edit the initial split statement:
my @items = split(/(?<!p\d)\s+/, $string);
Because not all my chunks are actually in the form of p and a digit... but actually anything.. like: [xyz abc/def].
I'm trying a few changes to that split but I get this error:
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!\S+)\s+/
Help?

Comment: @user961627 I edited the regex used by split, and changed the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: yes i did want the understand despite getting the help, to understand regex better, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have not shared your regular expression but you should use the *g* for global replace. Otherwise perl regular expression only replace the first match

```
my $teststring = "hello world";

$teststring =~ s/o/X/;
```

will become `hellX world`. but

```
$teststring =~ s/o/X/g;
```

will become `hellX wXrld` noticing all matches.

I think your problem is something like

```
my $teststring = ' A B C ';

$teststring =~ s/\s(\w)\s/ [$1] /ig;
```

yields `[A] B [C]`.   It is not doing B and the reason is that as part of matching **A** the regex machinery also consumed the space after A. And in the remaining string there is no space before B so it doesn't match.

But if you do a non greedy match like so

```
$teststring =~ s/\s(\w)\s*?/ [$1] /ig;
```

it yields `[A]  [B]  [C]`